# Get WPF combobox SelectedItem property and assign to a string variable in c# using MVVM pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm, data-binding

Can anyone tell me how to get the selected item of a combo box to a string variable?

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="cborevisions" ItemsSource="{Binding purchaseOrderViewModel.purchaseOrderDetailsCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" 
          Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="50" Foreground="Black" Margin="5,5">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding MatchesProposalRev.,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}" Width="50"/>
          </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

**C#:**

```
public ObservableCollection<PurchaseOrderDetailsViewModel> purchaseOrderDetailsCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _purchaseOrderDetailsCollection;
        }
        set
        {
            _purchaseOrderDetailsCollection = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("purchaseOrderDetailsCollection");
        }
    }
```

**C#:**

```
RevisionNo = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(purchaseOrderViewModel.purchaseOrderDetailsCollection.LastOrDefault().MatchesProposalRev) ? purchaseOrderViewModel.purchaseOrderDetailsCollection.LastOrDefault().MatchesProposalRev.ToString() : "";
```

Instead of passing "MatchesProposalRev", would like to pass combobox SelectedItem property to RevisionNo in the same way, would really appreciate for any suggestion/solution using as am very new to MVVM design pattern.

Thanks.

Comment: Add a property on your VM of the type that your collection contains and set up binding in your xaml `SelectedItem={Binding PropertyOnViewModel}`

Comment: Just bind the `SelectedItem` to y view model property.

Answer (score 0):

XAML:

```
<ComboBox SelectedItem={Binding SelectedPurchaseOrder}>
```

C#

```
private PurchaseOrderDetailsViewModel _selectedPurchaseOrder;
public PurchaseOrderDetailsViewModel SelectedPurchaseOrder
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedPurchaseOrder;
        }
        set
        {
            if(_selectedPurchaseOrder== value) return;
            _selectedPurchaseOrder= value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedPurchaseOrder));
        }
    }
```